# Cheap/Best Dashboard Solution for Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services and .Net

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services, charts, dashboard

We are a small software company providing a simple ERP solution to our client base based on Microsoft .Net and SQL Server. Our ERP has gathered a lot of data over the years and is at a point in time where implementing data mining, cleansing and analysis services such as dashboards would make sense.

My question is what are my options when it comes to providing users with simple interactive dashboards through our .Net base ERP or as part of a seperate solution. What is the cheapest best technology for providing an interactive dashboard solution to users high up in the managerial chain given the fact that we are already familiar working with .Net and MS SQL Server and that the customers already possess MS SQL Server licences? (Feel free to suggest any other solutions which you think does not directly relate to .Net too)

Please don't forget to mention licensing limitations/fees for these technologies as well if you can.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Implementing something like Sharepoint server solely for this purpose seems like a bit of an overkill to me but let me know what you think.

I've heard a lot about Dundas charts. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two fairly cheap options that come to mind are:

1. [DevExpress](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Reporting/) - $349
2. [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx) - $399

Both of these platforms will allow you to build an interactive dashboard using .NET. I haven't used DevExpress for a couple years, but have recently used Telerik. Both are great. Take a look at the demos, I think you'll be happy with the capabilities you get for the price.

Comment: Liked the telerik controls but is it just me or arent they that much interactive. I didnt see any interactivity in the demos.

Comment: @Harindaka,  Basically, the dashboard are not like a plug-and-play component.  You have to build your own dashboard making use of their components. Hence you have to write code to add more interactivity.

Comment: Also take a look at the Silverlight demos if you want to see more interactivity.

Comment: Have u guys had any experience with Dundas Charts and Dashboard components? Are they expensive? The demos look awesome. Im voting up this answer as its the best so far. Thanks guys

Comment: dundas is about $30,000 per year subscription. They aren't really a toolkit; they are a platform/IDE...

Comment: Telerik is more in our price range. Hence im marking this as the answer. Thanks for all the support.

Comment: I've used [DataReportive](http://datareportive.com/) and [chartio](https://chartio.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Excel is a very powerful tool for data analysis and its 'free', given most office users have it on their machine anyway http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/overview-of-online-analytical-processing-olap-HP010177437.aspx

Also - not knowing what your level of 'cheap' is, there is a set of tools out there where you can build very pretty dashboards: http://www.componentart.com/ ($1999)

I personally don't think implementing a sharepoint for this is overkill, as it was particularly meant to facilitate business communication. Also look into Powerpivot: http://www.powerpivot.com/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `Dundas`. it is and add-on for SQL Server Reporting Services and provide astonished visualization for .NET.

You can check sample [here](http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/start/samples/) or  [live demo](http://www.dundas.com/Dashboard/Start/LiveDemo/) (about 30000 a year)

Comment: 30,000 USD? :-O and thats for one year?

Comment: I was looking into the price of Dundas as well and found that they have a license for everything.  I wonder if the $30k/yr is "all inclusive".  You have to have a server licence, developer license, designer license, and even viewer licenses.  Seems a bit ridiculous if you ask me.  http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/resources/dundas-dashboard-licensing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

FYI Dundas licenses aren't annual - they are perpetual. There is an annual support and upgrade subscription you have the option of renewing each year. The licenses themselves never need to be renewed.